# How can i reduce the number of lines of code to change the color of button?

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

In this i want to reduce the number of lines of code in my JS file. I am using materialize bootstrap and here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('select').material_select();
  $('.buttonEnable').addClass('enableButtonColor');
});

$('.buttonMonitor').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('enableButtonColor');
  $('.buttonLaunch').removeClass('enableButtonColor');
  $('.buttonEnable').removeClass('enableButtonColor');
});

$('.buttonLaunch').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('enableButtonColor');
  $('.buttonMonitor').removeClass('enableButtonColor');
  $('.buttonEnable').removeClass('enableButtonColor');
});

$('.buttonEnable').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('enableButtonColor');
  $('.buttonMonitor').removeClass('enableButtonColor');
  $('.buttonLaunch').removeClass('enableButtonColor');
});
```

```css
.enableButtonColor {
  background-color: #8dc63f !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4 enableButton"> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonEnable">Enable</a> </div>
  <div class="col s4 launchButton"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonLaunch">Launch</a> </div>
  <div class="col s4 monitorButton"> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonMonitor">Monitor</a> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap whole row into a `div` with any class name and use this class to toggle active class on buttons `click`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buttonEnable').addClass('enableButtonColor');
  $(document).on('click', '.button-row a', function() {
    $('.button-row a').removeClass('enableButtonColor');
    $(this).addClass('enableButtonColor');
  });
});
```

```css
.enableButtonColor {
  background-color: #8dc63f !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s4 enableButton"> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonEnable">Enable</a> </div>
    <div class="col s4 launchButton"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonLaunch">Launch</a> </div>
    <div class="col s4 monitorButton"> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonMonitor">Monitor</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add some common class(like I used buttonClass ) in your all div. Then apply your jquery to that.

jquery:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('select').material_select();
  $('.buttonEnable').addClass('enableButtonColor');
});

$('.buttonClass').on('click','a',function() {
 
  $(this).closest('.buttonClass').siblings().find('a').removeClass('enableButtonColor');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('enableButtonColor');
   $(this).addClass('enableButtonColor');
});
```

```css
.enableButtonColor {
  background-color: #8dc63f !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4 enableButton buttonClass"> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonEnable ">Enable</a> </div>
  <div class="col s4 launchButton buttonClass"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonLaunch">Launch</a> </div>
  <div class="col s4 monitorButton buttonClass"> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonMonitor">Monitor</a> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var $btn = $(".s4 a");
    $btn.click(function() {
       $btn.removeClass("enableButtonColor");
       $(this).addClass("enableButtonColor");
    });
```

**Snippet**

```js
var $btn = $(".s4 a");
$btn.click(function() {
  $btn.removeClass("enableButtonColor");
  $(this).addClass("enableButtonColor");
});
```

```css
.enableButtonColor {
  background-color: #8dc63f !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4 enableButton"> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonEnable">Enable</a> </div>
  <div class="col s4 launchButton"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonLaunch">Launch</a> </div>
  <div class="col s4 monitorButton"> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn extraPadding buttonMonitor">Monitor</a> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good approach.Although it has higher time complexity but this should not be issue for items less then few thousands.

```js
$(".click-me").click(function(){
  $('.click-me').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="active click-me">Aasdf</a>
<a class="click-me">Basdf</a>
<a class="click-me">Casdf</a>
```